# PHP multiple substr on string

Tags: php, substr

I have a string for which I am provided a string index.

I am creating a process to read it and I am wondering if there is a php function that exists that I have overlooked or an unaware of to perform this process far more easily.

$data:

```
Invoice No..... Sale Type Desc...... Misc Amt.... Misc Acc.. Misc Acc Desc.....................................

FOCF219611      CUSTOMER                    -0.02 8050       TOOLS & SUPPLIES - SERVICE
FOCF219669      CUSTOMER                   -14.49 8050       TOOLS & SUPPLIES - SERVICE
```

$fieldIndexes:

```
Array (
  [0] => 15 
  [1] => 20 
  [2] => 12 
  [3] => 10
  [4] => 50
)
```

Split `$data` into `$headers` array:

```
array_push($headers, substr($data, 0, $fieldIndexes[0]));
array_push($headers, substr($data, $fieldIndexes[0], $fieldIndexes[1]));
array_push($headers, substr($data, $fieldIndexes[1], $fieldIndexes[2]));
array_push($headers, substr($data, $fieldIndexes[2], $fieldIndexes[3]));
array_push($headers, substr($data, $fieldIndexes[3], $fieldIndexes[4]));
```

Is there a function that can remove part of a string - like `array_shift` for a string? 
I was thinking I could loop the `$fieldIndexes`, extract the first length from the start of the string, and so on until the string is empty and condense this into 3 lines and make it portable for any number of fieldIndexes?

Desired Result:

```
Array
(
[HEADERS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Invoice No
        [1] => Sale Type Desc
        [2] => Misc Amt
        [3] => Misc Acc
        [4] => Misc Acc Desc

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Invoice No] => FOCF219611
        [Sale Type Desc] => CUSTOMER
        [Misc Amt] => -0.02
        [Misc Acc] => 8050
        [Misc Acc Desc] => TOOLS & SUPPLIES - SERVICE

    )
)
```

Comment: What is the desired output for the inputs you have specified?

Comment: you can use `fopen('php://temp', 'w+')` put the string into `temp` with `fwrite` then use `rewind` and `fgetc` to count the chars tell you hit offset etc. etc.  Stream wrapper if you prefer the file handles.

Comment: If you have some usable delimiters, you might look at strtok.

Comment: I have updated the question with the desired result

Comment: Can you update it to include more then just the header.  `array_combine` works good on CSV (delimited stuff) most the time, well I would slap an `array_fill_keys` and `array_replace` on there. But yea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function like this one to split using the chunk sizes.
Note: Since each size in the `$fieldIndexes` array didn't include the space between columns, I added one to each length (15+1, 20+1, ...)

```
<?php

$headerString ="Invoice No..... Sale Type Desc...... Misc Amt.... Misc Acc.. Misc Acc Desc.....................................";
$fieldIndexes = [ 15+1, 20+1, 12+1, 10+1,  50+1];


function getParts($string, $positions){
    $parts = array();

    foreach ($positions as $position){
        $parts[] = substr($string, 0, $position);
        $string = substr($string, $position);
    }

    return $parts;
}

print_r(getParts($headerString, $fieldIndexes));
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Invoice No..... 
    [1] => Sale Type Desc...... 
    [2] => Misc Amt.... 
    [3] => Misc Acc.. 
    [4] => Misc Acc Desc.....................................
)
```

Comment: Like this - very portable

Answer (score 0):

Like this (because I said it in the comments)

```
$str = 'Invoice No..... Sale Type Desc...... Misc Amt.... Misc Acc.. Misc Acc Desc.....................................';

$f = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
fwrite($f, $str);
rewind($f);
$headers = [];

$header = '';
while(false !== ($c = fgetc($f))){
    if($c != '.'){
        $header .= $c;
    }elseif(!empty($header)){
        $headers[] = trim($header);
        $header = '';
    }
}

print_r($headers);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Invoice No
    [1] => Sale Type Desc
    [2] => Misc Amt
    [3] => Misc Acc
    [4] => Misc Acc Desc
)
```

Note I did this without using an offset, but I mentioned it in the comments and I like doing weird things like this.  It's enjoyable.

Of course you could just do this for the same result:

```
$str = 'Invoice No..... Sale Type Desc...... Misc Amt.... Misc Acc.. Misc Acc Desc.....................................';

print_r(array_filter(array_map('trim',explode('.', $str))));
```

But that is far, far to easy.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0adf655251f0d742cb8647684680b974c42b5bca)

And if you don't like the keys being all wacky you can just lap an array_values on that sucker.

```
 print_r(array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim',explode('.', $str)))));
```

LOL, another monday.

**UPDATE**

You can use the file stream wappers to fix a file for CSV reading, too.  In PHP5.4 (I think or 5.3) the SplFileObj is missing `fgetcsv` and I used a trick with them to patch that class.... :)

This was my point (but there is a lot I don't know)

```
$str = 'Invoice No..... Sale Type Desc...... Misc Amt.... Misc Acc.. Misc Acc Desc.....................................
somedata .... someother stuff ... foobar ... hello ... world..
';

//pretend this is a real file
$f = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
fwrite($f, $str);
rewind($f);
$headers = [];
$num_headers = 0;

$i = 1;
while(false !== ($c = fgetcsv($f))){

     //if there is only one element assume the delimiter is wrong
    if(count($c) == 1){
        //you could test the string for multiple delimiters and change
        /*
         if(strpos($c, '.')){
            $regex = '/\.+/'
         }else if(strpos($c, '~')){
            $regex = '/~+/'
         } etc....
        */

        //use memory buffer to fix files with .'s but still read them as
        //a normal CSV file, php://memory is really fast.
        //and this gives us all the parsing benefits of fgetcsv
        //you could use any delimiter here you want.
        $fixed =  trim(preg_replace('/\.+/', ',', $c[0]),',');
        $m = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
        fwrite($m, $fixed);
        rewind($m);
        $c = fgetcsv($m);
    }
    //trim any spaces, not a bad idea anyway
    $c = array_map('trim', $c);

    //if no headers use the first line of file as the header
    if(empty($headers)){
        $headers = $c;
        //count them (see below)
        $num_headers = count($headers);
        continue;
    }

     //array_combine is a good choice for header => values
     //but the arrays have to be the same size
    if(count($c) != $num_headers) die("missing dilimter on line {$i}");

    $line = array_combine($headers, $c);

    //continue with normal csv opperation
    print_r($line);

    ++$i; //track the line number
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Invoice No] => somedata
    [Sale Type Desc] => someother stuff
    [Misc Amt] => foobar
    [Misc Acc] => hello
    [Misc Acc Desc] => world
)
```

**UPDATE**

As I mentioned in the comments (after finding out it was HTML).  You can use a DOM parser.  One I have used in the past is `PHPQuery` it's a bit dated now. But it's nice because you can use jQuery syntax.  For example say you have this

```
<ul id="title" >
    <li>header</li>
    <li>header</li>
    <li>header</li>
</ul>
```

You can find it with something like this (it's been a while, so if this is wrong sorry)

```
  $length =  $PHPQuery->find("#headers li")->lenght;

   for($i=0;$i<$lenght;++$i){
      echo $PHPQuery->find("#headers li:eq($i)")->text();
   }
```

You can even pull attributes using `->attr('href')` for example.  Basically you can take advantage of the HTML structure and pull what you need instead of converting it to text and trying to remove a bunch of "stuff"

Cheers!

Comment: The preriods '.' are unique to this report only - I want a portable solution for reports that dont have periods in the header

Comment: That begs the question what does the other ones have.  Are they files to begin with, there is a lot of missing information.  If the rest are CSV, I can show you how to fix this one to be CSV and read it the same as them.

Comment: For example is that whole file done in `.` dots or just the header.  I can code most anything, and I'm bored right now.

Comment: It is a HTML document - column headers across the top, data in columns below. Here is a sample of another file I had to process - http://oi66.tinypic.com/1zob6f5.jpg

Comment: Thanks for telling me ... now ... have you tried `PHPQuery` it's a dom library that lets you use jQuery selectors to parse a page.  HTML is like a whole other ball game,

Comment: It's a HTML doc attached to an email - I process the email, grab the attachment and then process all rows into a MySQL db. It's a real nuisance but a limit that is put on extracts from the system, without the field selectors it is impossible to determine headings start and finish spots...

Comment: If it has HTML markup in that's fine you can process it with a DOM parser which lets you take advantage of the HTML tags.